# Boolean Assignment Operators in C#

Tags: c#, boolean-operations

How does this `^=` Boolean Assignment Operator work in C#, and what is the mathematical name of the `^` operator? How it is different from the `&` and `|` operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` means one operand should be true or false, this will return false in cause of both true/false

Answer (score 9):

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx):

> Binary ^ operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For
>   integral types, ^ computes the bitwise exclusive-OR of its operands.
>   For bool operands, ^ computes the logical exclusive-or of its
>   operands; that is, the result is true if and only if exactly one of
>   its operands is true.

In math, this is called **mutually exclusive**.

Developer Use case:

You might have a certain UI where 2 input fields are required together (But both being empty is valid). In such a case you can use the XOR operator to check if one field is filled while the other is not.

How `^` differs from `&` and `|`:

- true & false => false;
- true | false => true;
- true ^ false => true;
- `true ^ true` => false while both `true & true` => true and `true | true` => true

Rules:

- &: both should be true to yield true.
- |: at least one should be true to yield true.
- ^: exactly one operand should be true to yield true.

Using `b1 ^= b2;` is equivalent to `b1 = b1 ^ b2;` so the above rules apply.

Comment: Therefore `b1 ^= b2;` will leave `b1` unchanged if `b2` is `false`, and will flip `b1` to the opposite value of what it was before if `b2` is `true`.